# Null pointer exception when I try to filter a List into a map

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have the follow scenario:

```
    Emp e1 = new Emp("key x", "modelCode x", "modelYear x1");
    Emp e2 = new Emp("key x", "modelCode x", "modelYear x2");
    Emp e3 = new Emp("key x", "modelCode y", "modelYear y1");
    Emp e4 = new Emp("key z", "modelCode z", "modelYear z1");
    Emp e5 = new Emp("key z", "modelCode z", "modelYear z1");

    Map<AnyEnum, List<Emp>> empsMap = new HashMap<AnyEnum, List<Emp>>();
    empsMap.put(AnyEnum.FOO_ONE, Arrays.asList(e1,e2,e3)); 
    empsMap.put(AnyEnum.FOO_TWO, Arrays.asList(e4,e5));
```

And now I'd like to separete it in another map, getting the total value for each yearCode as follows:

```
public static Map<String,Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>> getTotal(Map<AnyEnum, List<Emp>> empMap){
    Map<String,Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>> mapKey = new HashMap<String,Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>>();
    
    Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> mapModelCode = null;
    Map<String, Integer> mapModelYear = null;
    
    String key;
    String modelCode;
    String modelYear;
    
    int total= 0;
    List<Emp> empList;
    
    for (Map.Entry<AnyEnum, List<Emp>> entry : empMap.entrySet()) {
        empList = entry.getValue();
        
        for(Emp emp: empList) {
            key = emp.getKey();
            modelCode = emp.getModelCode();
            modelYear = emp.getModelYear();
            
            if(!mapKey.containsKey(key) ||
                mapKey.get(key).get(modelCode)== null) {
                
                mapModelCode = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>>();
                mapKey.put(key, mapaModelCode);
                
            }else {
                mapModelCode = mapKey.get(modelCode);
            }
            
            mapModelYear = mapModelCode.get(modelYear); //null pointer exception here
            
            if(mapModelYear == null) {
                mapModelYear = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                mapModelYear.put(modelYear, 0);
            }
        
            total= mapaModelYear.get(modelYear) +1;
            mapModelYear.put(modelYear, total);
            mapModelCode.put(modelCode, mapaModelYear);
            mapKey.put(key, mapaModelCode); 
        }
    }
    return mapKey;
}
```

I'd like the follow result:

```
{key x={modelCode x={modelYear x1=1}}}, 
{key x={modelCode x={modelYear x2=1}}},
{key x={modelCode y={modelYear y1=1}}},
{key z={modelCode z={modelYear z1=2}}}
```

But in the seccond interation, on the line appointed I get null pointer exception.

Comment: `mapModelCode = mapKey.get(modelCode);` should be `mapModelCode = mapKey.get(key).get(modelCode);`

Comment: if i do this I'll get the mapModelYear

Comment: Oh right, it should be `mapModelCode = mapKey.get(key);` --- The point is that the key value for `mapKey` should be `key`, not `modelCode`.

Answer (score -2):

i'm new in coding but itseems to me that your mapModelYear is not instanciated at the time you're calling it , it's value is null like you wrote it at first , it seems logic to me that you're getting a Nullpointer here.

Comment: no because, mapYearModel was initialized in the before if in the previous interation